# MutationObserver to detect change in null child element

Tags: javascript, iframe, mutation-observers, mutation-events

I have an iframe that is rendering content from another domain. Obviously I cannot access the `contentDocument` from the other domain (returns `null`). But when a user performs an action on the rendered iframe, it redirects back to my domain. So at that point I *am able* to read the document. Basically once the contentDocument is not `null`, I want to perform an action.

Currently I'm just trying to fire an alert if a child of the iframe (in this case its `contentDocument` mutates...

```
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(initializeObserver, 2000)
}

const initializeObserver = () => {
  const iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe')

  observer.observe(
    iframe,
    {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    }
  )
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if(mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      alert("SOMETHING HAPPENED!")
    }
  })
})
```

But the alert never fires even when child nodes are added and elements within the iframe change. I've read a lot of examples, but maybe I'm still missing how this works. Can someone help explain why this observer isn't triggering on the mutation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browsing context in an `<iframe>` has its `location` changed, the `src` attribute of the containing `<iframe>` doesn't change, so your page can not see any difference.

What you could do since you apparently control the other page is to [post a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to your main page.
Then you just have to listen for that message and you know your frame has come back.

```js
// in main
addEventListener("message", (evt) => {
  if( evt.origin === location.origin && evt.data === "I'm back" ) {
    // your page came back
  }
});
```

```js
// in framed page
top.postMessage( "I'm back", location.origin );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I don't control the other page, but they do redirect to my domain on certain user actions. I did consider the `postMessage` approach, but that would require a change from the other party. Once that change (return to my domain) happens, I can then get at the `src`. But if I'm understanding correctly, you're saying there's no way to observe when that becomes available, besides the other party firing a `postMessage` event?

Comment: I'm saying your page should call postMessage. For instance, you start the iframe pointing to `otherdomain.com`, there after some time they will redirect your iframe to `yourdomain.com/framed.html`. In this `framed.html` you will call postMessage.

Comment: OH, ok. That makes sense I think. I'll try this and see if it works. Thank you!